# Angular JS : How can I control elements injected into my view from a 3rd party library in Angular without using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm building a web app using Angular. On one view, I am loading a 3rd party script using angular-load, which in turn injects a form into my page. The problem is that the form doesn't do the proper validations and there are certain UI elements missing (disabling the button when clicked, two spinner loaders showing up, incorrect validation). I am currently using jquery and timeouts to disable and hide unwanted elements from the injected form, but I want to avoid using Jquery and do it in the proper angular way. How can I do that?

Example: I want to disable the submit button on click, but re-enable the button if the validation done by the script is incorrect.

Comment: use angular forms validation  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms.

Comment: My questions might not have been clear. The form is being injected dynamically into the view after the script loads, so I have to manipulate the dom dynamically and cannot do it in my code before hand. The injected form has its own validation script with it as well, I just want to disable parts of the form depending on the submit action as well as the validation result

Comment: I don't think there is a pure angular way of doing it because your form validation is controlled by injected javascript. So angular wont know the changes made by that injected scripts. and to let know angular you might have to do `$scope.$apply` and its not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem, and when you ask a question you get the same old "that's not the Angular way to do it". Right. I'll have **you** ask the 3rd party developer to rewrite the script in Angular for me!

I ran into the same problem today integrating a lead tracking script. The way I approached it was to simply grab the token from the page using a global.

I added this right to my controller, and it seemed to work fine.

```
$window.setTimeout(function() {
// not the greatest practice, but a $watch won't see my change. Wait a few seconds and get your lead id, then add to the lead. 
Lead.set("leadid_token",document.getElementById('leadid_token').value);
 }, 2000);
```